# Can I call a function to cal a server in iOS applicationWillTerminate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I, I want notify to my server when my iOS objective c application is closed by a user, and I want add a call into my applicationWillTerminate delegate function.

But I don't know if it is possible, because I have added a UILocalNotification and it isn't showed...

Could I call my server when the user close the app?

Comment: Why not inside other callback methods but applicationWillTerminate ?

Comment: Well, I have some functions in other methods, and I want know when app was killed not go to background.

Answer (score 0):

This method is rarely called and not reliable but why not to save some settings on these methods

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

so that when you open the app again you check these values and call the service you wanted

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if I wxecute my call in background, but the application is closed, I couldn't know if the app is killed or the user can give this to foreground because he send this to background. Hope be clear